# Facing issue in giving testcases and input in python for string Counter program

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

My code is giving runtime error. Can any tell me what is the thing I am doing wrong. The input defined in IDE(for ex. are n,m,p,q,r). n represent no of testcases, m represent length of string of p,q,r which is same. p,q,r is a string. My code is working fine if I not use n,m. I am giving n=1,m=4,p=AAAA,Q=AAAB,R=AABB output should be bob

```
from collections import Counter
n=input()
for _ in range(n):

m = input()
p = input()
q = input()
r = input()
m=len(p)=len(q)=len(r)
counts = Counter(p)
count = Counter(q)
coun = Counter(r)
max_freq = max(counts.values())
max_freq1 = max(count.values())
max_freq2 = max(coun.values())
a = m - max_freq
c = m - max_freq1
d = m - max_freq2
if a<c and a<d:
 print("bob")
elif c<a and c<d:
 print("ROM")
else:
 print("Mark")# your code goes here
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's the logic of this program?  In other words, what your code tries to achieve?  And lastly, what's the issue you run into?

Answer (score 1):

The data type for `n` is `str`. You need to cast it to integer.

```
>>> a = input()
42
>>> print(a, type(a))
42 <class 'str'>
>>> a = int(input())
42
>>> print(a, type(a))
42 <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime error was because of loop try now .

```
from collections import Counter
#n=input()
n=1
for _ in range(n):# problem was here !

#m = input()
#p = input()
#q = input()
#r = input()
#m=len(p)=len(q)=len(r)
 
 m=4
 p="AAAA"
 q="AAAB"
 r="AABB"
 counts = Counter(p)
 count = Counter(q)
 coun = Counter(r)
 max_freq = max(counts.values())
 max_freq1 = max(count.values())
 max_freq2 = max(coun.values())
 a = m - max_freq
 c = m - max_freq1
 d = m - max_freq2
 if a<c and a<d:
  print("bob")
 elif c<a and c<d:
  print("ROM")
 else:
  print("Mark")# your code goes here
```

***Happy Coding***